# ASP.NET Core [Require] non-nullable types

Tags: c#, validation, asp.net-core

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6662976/required-attribute-for-an-integer-value), the question was posed how to validate non-nullable required types.

The provided solution to make the field nullable like the following is not desirable in my case.

```
[Required]
public int? Data { get; set; }
```

How can you change the behavior to instead make the following fail validation in the cases where the field is omitted from the request.

```
[Required]
public int Data { get; set; }
```

I have tried a custom validator, but these do not have information about the raw value and only see the default `0` value. I have also tried a custom model binder but it seems to work at the level of the entire request model instead of the integer fields which a want. My binder experiment looks like this:

```
public class RequiredIntBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public Task BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        if (bindingContext.ModelType != typeof(int))
            throw new InvalidOperationException($"{nameof(RequiredIntBinder)} can only be applied to integer properties");

        var value = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.BinderModelName);
        if (value == ValueProviderResult.None)
        {
            bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Failed();
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        return new SimpleTypeModelBinder(bindingContext.ModelType).BindModelAsync(bindingContext);
    }
}

public class RequiredIntBinderProvider : IModelBinderProvider
{
    public IModelBinder GetBinder(ModelBinderProviderContext context)
    {
        if (context == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context));
        }

        if (context.Metadata.ModelType == typeof(int))
        {
            return new BinderTypeModelBinder(typeof(RequiredIntBinder));
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

and is registered with mvc like this

```
options.ModelBinderProviders.Insert(0, new RequiredIntBinderProvider());
```

but the model binder is never used. I feel like I might be close but cannot connect the last dots.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### Solution working with json requests

You **cannot validate an already created model instance**, because a non-nullable property has always a value (no matter whether it was assigned from json or is a default value). The **solution is to report the missing value already during deserialization**.

Create a contract resolver

```
public class RequiredPropertiesContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
    protected override JsonObjectContract CreateObjectContract(Type objectType)
    {
        var contract = base.CreateObjectContract(objectType);

        foreach (var contractProperty in contract.Properties)
        {
            if (contractProperty.PropertyType.IsValueType
                && contractProperty.AttributeProvider.GetAttributes(typeof(RequiredAttribute), inherit: true).Any())
            {
                contractProperty.Required = Required.Always;
            }
        }

        return contract;
    }
}
```

and then assign it to `SerializerSettings`:

```
services.AddMvc()
        .AddJsonOptions(jsonOptions =>
        {
            jsonOptions.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new RequiredPropertiesContractResolver();
        });
```

The `ModelState` is then invalid for non-nullable properties with the `[Required]` attribute if the value is missing from json.

---

### Example

Json body

```
var jsonBody = @"{ Data2=123 }"
```

is invalid for model

```
class Model
{
    [Required]
    public int Data { get; set; }

    public int Data2 { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. What is the point of using a statically typed language if everything can be nullable. This makes no sense to me, I am mad at aspnetcore right now.

Comment: Is there a similar solution for `System.Text.Json`  ?

Comment: @AliRezaSabouri Yes: https://thom.ee/blog/clean-way-to-use-required-value-types-in-asp-net-core/

Answer (score 6):

Everything from the request is just a string. The modelbinder matches up keys in the request body with property names, and then attempts to coerce them to the appropriate type. If the property is not posted or is posted with an empty string, that will obviously fail when trying to convert to an int. As a result, you end up with the default value for the type. In the case of an `int` that's `0`, while the default value of `int?` is `null`.

*Only after this binding process is complete* is the model then validated. Remember you're validating the *model* not the post body. There's no reasonable way to validate the post body, since again, it's just a a bunch of key-value pair strings. Therefore, in the case of an `int` property that's required, but not posted, the value is `0`, which is a perfectly valid value for an int, and the validation is satisfied. In the case of `int?`, the value is `null`, which is *not* a valid int, and thus fails validation. That is why the nullable is required, if you want to require a non-nullable type have a value. It's the only way that an empty value can be differentiated from simply a "default" value.

If you are using view models, as you should be, this should not be an issue. You can bind to a nullable int with a required attribute, and you will be assured that it *will* have a value, despite being nullable, if your model state is valid. Then, you can map that over to a straight int on your entity. That is the correct way to handle things.

Comment: If there is no way to achieve this within ASP.NET I find it an unfortunate design choice. When consuming the request model, there is not way for me to know that the field is required without actually inspecting the type, so you lose some of the intent. I might look at creating a model binder that sets the default value to "int.Min" and have a validator interpret this as null. While a hack, it should do the job.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Regardless, this is not an "unfortunate design choice". It's entirely logical. The values of `0` or even `int.MinValue` are entirely appropriate values. The whole reason nullables exists is for disambiguation, i.e. to actually indicate `null` rather than simply `default`. You're trying to shoehorn logic onto this that is actually incorrect.

Comment: I agree with you in general, but I rely on the [ApiController] attribute to run validation on my requests before reaching my controller actions. This renders your point moot, since the "0 representing null" case is never handled in my code. I guess I should have mentioned this in the question - my only goal is to reject requests as invalid if they to not provide values for all the required fields. Thus, the nullable required property no longer makes sense since it will always have a value.

Comment: I think you're looking at this upside down and backwards. The model you bind to should capture the states you care about. If you want to assume that an int always has a value then defaulting to `0` and not validating whether something was actually submitted is the correct path. If, however, you want to *know* that nothing was posted, then that's where a nullable comes in. It captures that information, which then allows you to handle that specific case, such as by returning a validation error. The automatic `ModelState` check, plays along with this, so I'm not sure what your point is there.

Comment: The automatic modelstate check does not reject requests that omit required fields. I want it to do so without having nullable fields that are not nullable in practice.

Comment: We're talking past each other here. Let me try to be a little more clear. If omission is a possibility, then the property is not in fact "not nullable in practice". *In practice*, you need the nullable to determine that it was omitted. There's no other way to make that determination, as any other potential value for an int other than `null` could be an actual posted value.

Comment: They are "not nullable in practice" if the modelstate validation would reject them automatically as invalid - then, code in my controller actions would never run if a required property was omitted. So from the perspective of the controller code, the required fields cannot be null by omission. I don't think I can make it any clearer, so if this does not make sense to you I suggest we stop the discussion.

Comment: @ChrisPratt I balk at [Required] int? first, but after reading your explanation, they appear very reasonable.

Answer (score 2):

> non-nullable required types.

You do not. It is either required - then there is no sense in it being nullable - or it is not required, then you nullable makes sense, but it makes no sense to require it.

Attributes are always for the whole request. You are in a logical problem because you try to use them not as intended.

If it is optional, the user should actually submit a patch, not a put/post.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're arguing for. I don't want the interger property to be nullable when it is required. This seems to be the same as what you're saying. However, .net does not treat it as a validation error if the required field is omitted. The example using the nullable property is the workaround that I want to avoid.

Answer (score 2):

There is an approach similar to that provided by [the top answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56391661/4362799), but it also

- Allows you to provide custom error messages. No leaking of JSON deserializer errors or annoying conversions.
- Supports value types bound from non-body sources, such as query params. Those sources don't use the JSON contract.
- You could theoretically make it work with any popular JSON deserializer, as well as body formats other than JSON.

Your attempt at making a custom model binder was close to what I eventually ended up figuring out. The missing detail is that the model binder won't work with FromBody JSON, since the JSON deserializer greedily binds the entire input model at once. To fix that, you need to get rid of the BodyModelBinder and create a custom value provider that is able to parse JSON.

> - For simple cases, use [BindRequired].
> - When you also need to bind data from the body (JSON), use the required keyword.
> - If you want the model errors that JSON binding produces to be good, create a custom value provider.
> - And if you need custom property-specific error messages and/or want to make all non-nullable value types required by default, implement a
>   custom model binder.

https://thom.ee/blog/clean-way-to-use-required-value-types-in-asp-net-core/

https://github.com/ea-ae/required-value-types/

The implementation is a bit long, but easily copy-pastable. The final result is that you can get your input models working like this:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Optional error message")]
public int Id { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 1):

There was the way to do that, at least it works for me, try `[BindRequired]` for non-nullable types.

Comment: This does not seem to work in .NET Core 3.1 anymore https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62279845/validating-non-nullable-property-in-body-as-required-aspnetcore-3-1/62280068#62280068

Comment: It works with ASP.NET Core (latest .NET 7), as long as the binding source isn't [FromBody] aka JSON.