# how to create dto validation for nested objects

Tags: c#, .net

I started with an API endpoint to create a new order for one customer by its customer id

```
[HttpPost("{id:int}/orders")]
public async Task<ActionResult<object>> CreateCustomerOrderByIdAsync(CreateCustomerOrderByIdDto createCustomerOrderByIdDto)
{
    // ...
}
```

So the DTO itself should validate the whole request. The customer id is a required field, the order positions are optional, the order itself can be empty.

```
public class CreateCustomerOrderByIdDto
{
    [FromRoute]
    [Required]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [FromBody]
    public OrderPosition[] OrderPositions { get; set; }
}
```

Each `OrderPositions` knows about the `ProductId` and the `Amount`. Both fields are required for this instance in the array.

```
public class OrderPosition
{
    [Required]
    public int ProductId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Range(1, int.MaxValue)]
    public int Amount { get; set; }
}
```

When I call the endpoint https://localhost:5001/customers/1/orders with the following json body

```
{
    "orderPositions": [{}]
}
```

I would expect a 400 because the array holds an object with no `ProductId` or `Amount` field. But instead of the error it takes the default value for integers which is `0`. How can I validate each `OrderPosition` inside the `OrderPositions` array too?

Comment: You'll need to change your `int ProductId` to a nullable int like `int? ProductId` as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6662976/required-attribute-for-an-integer-value)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `Range` on the `ProductId` as well. If your ProductId starts from 1 then it would look like below:

```
[Required]
[Range(1, int.MaxValue)]
public int ProductId { get; set; }
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. So the correct fix for this is `public class OrderPosition
    {
        [Required]
        [Range(1, int.MaxValue)]
        public int ProductId { get; set; }
        
        [Required]
        [Range(1, int.MaxValue)]
        public int Amount { get; set; }
    }` ? because with a range starting at 0 it just takes the default value for integers?

Comment: `[Required]` seems to be redundant, because the `Range` attribute seems to handle it. But what if you would want to validate an optional field only if set? Currently the `Range` attribute would mark that field as required

Comment: Right you can remove Required, And you can keep the Amount's range from 0 unless 1 is the minimum Amount you expect