# ValidationAttribute is not working on my asp.net mvc?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, data-annotations, customvalidator

I am trying to handle customValidation, using class object ValidationAttribute to my Model class. I cant seem to achieve correctly and need some help to improve my logic. The logic i want here when leaving@Html.EditorFor(). Must validate error from model/custom-class. I debug it does not hit any of my controller. The form does saves well on db, need validation to work.

```
// Model
  [Required(ErrorMessage = "This field is required")]
 [CustomValidation(ErrorMessage = "This field is required")]
        public int CellNumber { get; set; }

// CustomValidation.cs
  public class CustomFormValidation:ValidationAttribute
    {
        protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
        {
            var registration = (RegistrationTrainingForm)validationContext.ObjectInstance;
            if(registration.CellNumber==null)
            {
                return new ValidationResult("This field is required");
            }
                
            return base.IsValid(value, validationContext);
        }
    }

// Controller

        //GET:TrainingRegForm/Create/WebRequest.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult SubmitRegDetails([Bind(Include= "Id, Title, FirstName, LastName, Position, Company, StreetAddress, StreetAddressLine, City, StateProvince, ZipCode,Email, CellNumber, DietaryRequirement")]TrainingRegForm eNtsaTraining)
        {
            if(ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                eNtsaTraining.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
                db.TrainingRegs.Add(eNtsaTraining);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("SaveRegForm");
            }

            // Validates when empty.
            if(ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("SaveRegForm");
            }
            return View(eNtsaTraining);
        }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Required attribute for an integer value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6662976/required-attribute-for-an-integer-value)

Comment: I see the attribute but don't see usage.

Comment: Where do you use your attribute ?

Comment: @Guru and Arsalan. Here is my Attribute but i dont think it works.  public class CustomFormValidation:ValidationAttribute
    {
        protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
        {
            var registration = (RegistrationTrainingForm)validationContext.ObjectInstance;
            if(registration.CellNumber==null)
            {
                return new ValidationResult("This field is required");
            }
                
            return base.IsValid(value, validationContext);
        }
    }

Comment: @mailertestmail you have this code in question. Where do you use the `CustomFormValidation`? What field/class do you mark with it?

Comment: @Guru i am using [CustomValidation(ErrorMessage = "This field is required")]

Comment: i see cellNumber is int, your validation checks for null, but int default value is 0

Comment: @Nonik yes, would this be reason why my field does not validate on my Razor(View)@html.EditorFor(); when leaving the text?

Comment: Yes, you either change to the type  of  nullable int or string

Comment: I did change the data type, still its not working.@Guru the table definition is TrainingRegForm it has the table fields name made a change from the CustomValidation.cs. I still not getting it write.